# Adding multiple attributes to a udev device entry in a Linux driver

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, udev

I am writing a simple char driver which accesses a PCI card. It is registered to sysfs with the help of a new class and accessible under `/dev/foodev`. Now I would like to access multiple parameters of the device in a convenient way. I thought of registering multiple attributes to the device (via `device_create_file()`) which would then be visible as following:

```
/dev/foodev
    ../version
    ../status
    ../control
```

Therefore I defined my attributes as described in [Documentation/driver-model/device.txt](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/driver-model/device.txt) and registered them to the class' `dev_attrs` attribute as described by [GregKH on his blog](http://kroah.com/log/blog/2013/06/26/how-to-create-a-sysfs-file-correctly/) as following (code stripped of all return value verifications):

```
static int __init foo_init(void)
{
    int rv;
    dev_t devNbr;

    /* Create device class */
    fooClass = class_create(THIS_MODULE, CLASS_NAME);

    fooClass->dev_attrs = foo_attrs; /* my group of attributes */

    /* Allocate device number */
    rv = alloc_chrdev_region(&devNbr, 0, 1, DEVICE_NAME);
    foo_majNbr = MAJOR(devNbr);

    /* Registering driver */
    rv = pci_register_driver(&foo_driver);

    ...
}
```

Then the `probe` function registers every device as char device and connects them to the class. In a last step the attributes (here just one) get registered as files:

```
static int __devinit foo_probe(struct pci_dev *dev,
    const struct pci_device_id *devId)
{
    struct foo_dev *foo_dev = 0;
    int rv = 0;

    /* Allocate memory in Kernel (for parameters) */
    foo_dev = kzalloc(sizeof(*foo_dev), GFP_KERNEL);
    foo_dev->pci_dev = dev;

    foo_dev->devNbr = MKDEV(foo_majNbr, 1);

    /* Add class to device */
    foo_dev->dev = device_create(fooClass, NULL, foo_dev->devNbr,
        foo_dev, DEVICE_NAME);

    /* Add char device */
    cdev_init(&foo_dev->cdev, &foo_fops);

    /* Enabling device */
    rv = pci_enable_device(dev);

    ...

    /* ----> Register attribute as file <---- */
    device_create_file(foo_dev->dev, &dev_attr_bar);

    ...
}
```

My problem: The attribute does not show up in udev as I intend it to do. I still see only the device `/dev/foodev` without "subfiles" for the attributes. Having a closer look at `/sys/class/fooClass/fooDev/` I see a file `bar` to which I can read and write as desired but it is apparently ignored by udev:

- First: Why, what do I possibly wrong?
- Second: What is the relation between my three different structures, all containing a `struct device` (`pci_dev`, `dev` and `cdev`)? I know after reading ch. 14 of LDD that I create a kobject for all of them. I know also that the pci_dev is connected to the bus and I guess the cdev is the one I want a user to access. Following figure 14-1 of LDD I assume to create the following structure in the device model:

  ```
  Buses        Devices        Classes
    |             |              |
    v             v              v
  pci_dev <---- cdev            dev
    ^                            |
    |                            |
    +----------------------------+
  ```

  Correct?

Comment: Seems that you're confusing sysfs and udev.

Comment: Could you be more specific please? I see sysfs as a file system storing all connected devices. udev then reads out specific devices stripping away information like if the device was connected to a bus or belongs to a class

Comment: There is a good explanation of sysfs and all the related stuff in Linux Device Drivers, chapter 14. It's available online for free.

Comment: You want one device in /dev, to correspond to your single device.  The corresponding (single) sysfs directory will have one file per attribute that you want to expose.

Comment: Thank you all for your feedback. I studied ch. 14 and tried to be more specific in my question since I have still not obtained the desired solution.

Comment: What do you mean by `udev`?  If you mean you want those attribute files to appear in `/dev`, then what we've been saying is that that is not how to use the linux kernel.  Your device should have one device file in `/dev`.  Period.  It can expose many attribute files in sysfs.  To help us understand the question, you should probably provide some motivation as to WHY you want these files in /dev.

Comment: Thanks @Peter, I guess I still have a comprehension problem concerning `udev`: I thought that once a device is recognized as such by `udev` it gets copied from `/sysfs/class` to `/dev` containing the total tree (`/dev/foodev/attr1`, `/dev/foodev/attr2`...). But apparently I got that wrong, sorry. Why I want to do so: As I wrote at the beginning of the question its all about convenience, so a user can access the device's attribute without entering long paths but just type `cat /dev/foodev/version` to see the version of it as an example.

Comment: OK, I understand what you want, but it's not how the kernel works.  Just modify your definition of "convenience" and tell your users to type `cat /sysfs/<whatever file>`.  You can also put such things in the `proc` filesystem.  This is "not recommended" by kernel developers, but the API still works, and it is very convenient.

Comment: Love your sarcasm ;) But I got it, so `/udev`is just for devices. In this case my question is answered and I will change my approach. Thanks for your endurance in explaining! :)